# XGBoost JSON model in android studio using Chaquopy

Tags: python, android, json, xgboost, chaquopy

I am implementing an android app that makes predictions over some sounds using chaquopy. the XGboost was used to make this model which is in json. I'm using chaquopy latest version (10). As chaquopy supports xgboost this module is being installed but when I try to load the json module it doesn't allow it. I would like to know why I can't load my model and if is there a way to do it?

My python script:

```
import xgboost as xgb
from os.path import dirname, join

from xgboost.sklearn import XGBClassifier
def main ():
    filename = join(dirname(__file__), "model.json")
    model = XGBClassifier()
    model.load_model("model.json")
    #out=model.get_params()


    #with open(filename, "r") as fin:
    #   data=fin.read().lower()



    return ""+str(model)+""
```

the error:

```
/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.chaquo_proj2, PID: 15388
    com.chaquo.python.PyException: XGBoostError: [15:38:08] xgboost/src/common/io.cc:100: Opening model.json failed: No such file or directory
```

however, I do have the json file there.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and solved it successfully.
One thing
The version of xgboost will same while saving the model and loading the model.
For me, I used [xgboost==1.1.1](https://pypi.org/project/xgboost/1.0.1/)

For the saving model I used this code -

```
import pickle
file_ = 'XGBoost_.json'
XGmodel.save_model(file_)
```

To load and use the model use this code -

```
import pickle
from os.path import dirname, join
import xgboost as xgb

print(xgb.__version__)  #to check the version
xgr = xgb.XGBRegressor()
filename = join(dirname(__file__), 'XGBoost_.json')
xgr.load_model(filename)
print(xgr)
```

Try this hope so it will work for you also

Answer (score 0):

You correctly set the `filename` variable based on `__file__`, but then you forgot to use that variable when calling `load_model`.

Comment: unfortunatly no... later i tried the script like this :
`
import xgboost as xgb
from os.path import dirname, join
from xgboost.sklearn import XGBClassifier
def main ():
  filename = join(dirname(__file__), "model.json")
 model = XGBClassifier()
 imp=model.load_model(filename)
 imp2=imp.get_params()
 return str(imp2)
`
The error :
`
XGBoostError: [10:32:17] xgboost/include/xgboost/json.h:65: Invalid cast, from Null to Array
`

Comment: OK, I assume it's you who created [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/571), so let's continue the discussion there.